# resize all images while maintaining the aspect ratio of each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm fairly new to this stuff and I've got a small problem — what I'm trying to do is resize all of the images on a web page (more specifically, the images within each element with the id #post) and scale them down a bit

```
var currentWidth = $("#post img").width();
$("#post img").each(function () {
    $(this).css({'width': currentWidth / 1.5 + "px"});
});
```

The problem is that I think it's grabbing the width of the first image and using that for all of them, so they all end up being the same size as the first scaled down image. Any way to fix this so that each image's width grabbed and properly scaled down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct - you're getting a single width and using it throughout the loop. You're already halfway there, using `this` within the loop. Just follow that through:

```
$("#post img").each(function () {
    var currentWidth = $(this).width();

    if (currentWidth > 900) {
      $(this).css({'width': currentWidth / 1.5 + "px"});
    }
});
```

Comment: ah I should of seen that thank you very much — would it be possible to limit this resizing only if the image in the post is greater than 900px? I tried throwing a conditional in there, wrapping $(this).css({'width': currentWidth / 1.5 + "px"}); with if (currentWidth > 900) { } but it broke